# How can move ajax to global javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

I put my ajax here :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\resources\views\users\create.blade

The code is like this :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <section class="content-header">
        ...
    </section>
    <div class="content">
       ...
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#no").change(function() {
                $.getJSON("{{ url('/users/no') }}/" + $("#id").val(), function(data) {
                    ...     
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

It works

But I want to move it to global  js

My globaljs here :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\public\js\main.js

I move the ajax there. But there exist error :

> 404 (Not Found)

How can I solve it?

Comment: What request is resulting in a 404 error?

Comment: Check the mapping of the Ajax URL `$.getJSON("{{ url('/users/no') }}/" + $("#id").val()` it gives you 404 because you are moving the resource from: `C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\resources\views\users\create.blade` to `C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\public\js\main.js` but not changing the way it's looking for it (__[URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)__)